# ASP.NET AJAX AsyncFileUpload UploadedComplete not fires

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Thanks for your attention in advance,
I'm new to ASP.NET AJAX AsyncFileUpload so I've created an aspx page to test it but it seems there's some bug with that control because the server side UploadedComplete event does not fire.

the aspx :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

and the code behind

```
public partial class Tester : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Label1.Text = "OK";
    }
}
```

would anyone please let me know why it does not work?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

When you use AsyncFileUpload you must set the right params in the "form" tag, that is placed in your Page or MasterPage:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

If you don't set the right enctype `enctype="multipart/form-data"` method **UploadedComplete will never fire**, and you won't be able to get **FileUpload.FileBytes** since **FileUpload.HasFile** returns true only during UploadedComplete execution.

Besides, prevoius versions of AsyncFileUpload didn't work on Chrome. Version from 4.1.50731.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't want to use an updatepanel and uploadfile control together. It boils down to the same reasons you can't set the file of an uploadfile, security.